# Count minutes between two dates grouping by day/hour

Tags: php, date-difference

I have the following array:

```
$periods = array(
    ['begin' => '2013-08-14 10:00:00', 'end' => '2013-08-14 11:30:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-14 11:40:00', 'end' => '2013-08-14 11:45:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-14 11:45:00', 'end' => '2013-08-14 11:52:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-08 07:00:00', 'end' => '2013-08-08 09:25:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-09 23:50:00', 'end' => '2013-08-10 00:25:00']
);
```

What I want is to count the minutes between each period grouping by day/hour to have something like this:

```
date                  minutes
2013-08-14 10:00:00 : 60
2013-08-14 11:00:00 : 42
2013-08-08 07:00:00 : 60
2013-08-08 08:00:00 : 60
2013-08-08 09:00:00 : 25
2013-08-09 23:00:00 : 10
2013-08-10 00:00:00 : 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

The array:

```
$periods = array(
    ['begin' => '2013-08-14 10:00:00', 'end' => '2013-08-14 11:30:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-14 11:40:00', 'end' => '2013-08-14 11:45:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-14 11:45:00', 'end' => '2013-08-14 11:52:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-08 07:00:00', 'end' => '2013-08-08 09:25:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-09 23:50:00', 'end' => '2013-08-10 00:25:00']
);
```

The code:

```
$period_difference = array();
foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
    $dateTimes = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime($interval['begin']),
        new DateInterval('PT1M'),
        new DateTime($interval['end'])
    );

    foreach ($dateTimes as $dt) {
        $period_difference[$dt->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')] = isset($period_difference[$dt->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')]) ? $period_difference[$dt->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')]+1 : 1;
    }
}
```

To test on phpio.net: http://phpio.net/s/idl